# finding the kernel

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm reading the solution to an exam problem. Consider $\phi$ defined as

$$\phi: \mathbb{Z}_{7}[x]\rightarrow M_{2}(\mathbb{Z}_{7});\quad\quad f \mapsto  f\pmatrix{ 0&2 \\ 2&2}.$$

The solution says that $x^2+5x+3\in \operatorname{ker} \phi,$ but I'm not able to grasp why this is the case. Can someone enlighten me?

The argument for why this is the case is the following.
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 2\\ 2 & 2 \end{array}\right)^{2}=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 4 & 4\\ 4 & 1 \end{array}\right)=4\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right)+2\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 2\\ 2 & 2 \end{array}\right)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $\mathbb{Z}_7$, we have $-2 = 5$ and $-4 = 3$. Therefore, if we let $A = \left(\begin{matrix}
 0&2 \\ 
2 & 2
\end{matrix}\right)$, the equality $A^2 = 4I + 2A$ with $\mathbb{Z}_7$ coefficients is equivalent to $$0 = A^2 - 2A - 4I = A^2 + 5A + 3I = \phi(X^2 + 5X + 3).$$

Answer (score 2):

You have a map $\phi: \mathbb{Z_7} \rightarrow M_2(\mathbb{Z_7})$ such that  $\ f \mapsto f \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 2 \\ 2 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$. Basically you evaluate all possible linear combinations of the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 2 \\ 2 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$, which we'll call $A$ for brevity, as f varies in $\mathbb{Z_7}[x]$.

When does $\phi$ map a polynomial to $0$? It happens exactly when $f\in I(A)$, where $I(A)=\{p\in\mathbb{Z_7}[x] | p(A)=0\}$. We denote this set $I(A)$ because it is also an ideal in the ring $\mathbb{Z_7}[x]$. We would like to find a polynomial that generates $I$ - we'll call it $m(t)$. To find it we first calculate the characteristic polynomial of $A$, which is $p(t)=det(A-tI)$. Hamilton-Cayley's Theorem tells us that $p(t) \in I(A)$, so we know that $m(t) | p(t)$. We also know that the roots of both $p(t)$ and $m(t)$ are all the eigenvalues of A, which may eventually appear in $m(t)$ with a smaller algebraic multiplicity. However, we see that $p(t)=det(A-tI)= t^2-2t-4 \equiv t^2 +5t +3 \ (7)$ has two distinct roots, thus it must coincide with $m(t)$ for they are both of degree 2 and monic (we usually choose $m(t)$ with leading coefficient equal to 1).

Comment: I can't find any roots of $t² +5t +3 (mod 7)$, so what are the roots? And how do we know that both $p(t)$ and $m(t)$ are all the eigenvalues of A? And how do we know that the degree of $m(t)$ is not less than 2?

Comment: The roots of $p(t)$ are all the eigenvalues because of how we define $p(t)$. As regards $m(t)$, consider this: if $q(t)\in I(A) \Rightarrow q(A)=0$, so if we choose $v \in \mathbb{Z_7} | Av= \lambda v \Rightarrow q(A)(v)=q(\lambda)(v)=0 \Rightarrow (x-\lambda) | m(t)$. That being said, once you know that the roots are distinct, you know that $Deg(p(t))=Deg(m(t))$. As for the roots, we know they are $t_{1,2}=-\frac{5}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{13}}{2} \equiv -\frac{5}{2} \pm \frac{4}{2} \equiv 1 \pm 2 \ (7)$

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand why this is the case $q(A)(v)=q(λ)(v)=0⇒(x−λ)|m(t)$. And I still can't grasp why having distinct roots imply that $Deg(p(t))=Deg(m(t))$

Comment: And I'm bit confused about the roots, correct me if I'm wrong but isn't the definiton of a root $\alpha$ that $f(\alpha)=0$. So Why is $t(-1)=(-1)²-5+3=-1=6\neq0 (mod 7)$?

Comment: We want to show that $  \lambda \in Sp(A)  \Rightarrow m(\lambda)= 0$. We know that $(m(t))=I(A)$, so if we show that $\forall q(t) \in I(A), q(\lambda)=0 \Rightarrow m(\lambda)=0$. Let's take $q(t)=a_{0}+a_{1}x+a_{2}x^2+\dots +a_{n}x^n \in I(A) \Leftrightarrow q(A) \equiv 0 \Leftrightarrow q(A)(v)=0 \ \forall v \in \mathbb{Z_7} \ \Leftrightarrow a_{0}+a_{1}(Av)+a_{2}(Av)^2+ \dots +a_{n}(Av)^2=0$. In particular, if we choose $v$ such that  $Av= \lambda v \Rightarrow a_{0}+a_{1}\lambda v+a_{2}(\lambda)^2v+\dots +a_{n}(\lambda)^n v= q(\lambda)(v)=0$. $v \neq 0 \Rightarrow q(\lambda)=0$.

Comment: About the roots, I am terribly sorry: I made a huge mistake: $\sqrt{13} \not\equiv \sqrt{4} \ mod (7)$. Let's do this again: $t^2-2t-4=0 \Leftrightarrow t_{1,2}= 1 \pm \sqrt{5} \equiv 1 \pm i\sqrt{2} \equiv 1 \pm 3i$, thus we see that the roots are distinct. We also know that they are both roots of $m(t)$,  so $m(t)$ has degree at least 2. So we have $p(t) \in I(A)=(m(t)) \Leftrightarrow m(t) | p(t)$ and $Deg(p(t))=Deg(m(t)) \Rightarrow m(t)=p(t)$.

Comment: I don't understand how you can do this $1±\sqrt5≡1±i\sqrt2$

Comment: $\sqrt{5} \equiv \sqrt{-2} \ mod \ (7)$ because $5 \equiv -2 \ mod \ (7)$